# Dynamic table cell height (content cut off)

Tags: ios, uitableview, cell

I'm trying to create a table view with cells that have dynamic heights, everything seemed to work fine, but then I noticed this strange problem.
When I scroll the list down and go back up, some of the cells appear to not fully draw the content.

Correct content: https://www.dropbox.com/s/eqsx4p6dmsofrko/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-03%20at%2010.30.11%20AM.png

Content cut of: https://www.dropbox.com/s/qqelftkc5jzetk5/Screen%20Shot%202012-05-03%20at%2010.30.19%20AM.png

I create all my cells here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";
    ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    Item *item = [self.activity objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.projectLabel.text = item.project;
    cell.descriptionLabel.text = item.description;
    cell.timeLabel.text = item.time;
    cell.timeAgoLabel.text = item.timeAgo;
    //cell.avatar = [UIImageView item.avatar];

    cell.descriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.descriptionLabel sizeToFit];

    // remove the right arrow
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    //[self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimationNone];

    return cell;
}
```

And use this to change the height of the cells:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";
    ItemCell *cell = (ItemCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    CGSize descriptionHeight = [cell.descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    NSInteger height = cell.projectLabel.frame.origin.y + cell.projectLabel.frame.size.height;
    height += descriptionHeight.height + 30;

    NSLog(@"height: %d", height);

    return height;
}
```

Comment: I can't see the photos..

Comment: *After checking the photos* - Strange. Never had such problem. How much cells are there? I mean that maybe it's because of a memory leak

Comment: I only created 20 cells, I've used the storyboard to create a custom cell, nothing much is happening yet

Comment: Strangely it only happens to cell that go out of the screen on top, once I scroll the list and a cell hits the bottom, it goes back to normal.
I think it might have something to do with the heightForRowAtIndexPath, when I set a static height like 120, everything is normal, but when I set it at 100 I get the same problem

Comment: Maybe it must be more than a specific height to display the required amount of data :/ Try to override its initialization

Comment: I found out the problem was because I reused the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier cell, now I'm just grabbing the text directly from the data array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to grab the text from the datafeed instead of using the dequeued cell.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried calling [self setNeedsDisplay] to repaint the table view?

Comment: I called it on both the table and the cell, but doesn't seem to help

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this code works, but you are never creating a cell in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  I suspect it was omitted in your question.

Move the line `[cell.descriptionLabel sizeToFit];` from your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to above this line

```
CGSize descriptionHeight = [cell.descriptionLabel.text sizeWithFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:18.0f] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(265.0f, CGFLOAT_MAX) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

in your `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`

and then call

```
[cell setNeedsLayout];
[cell setNeedsDisplay];
```

Afterwards.

Comment: I'm using the storyboard with a prototype cell and just re-using that one. Even without the sizeToFit it has the same problem.
Once a cell goes above the display, it cuts of part of the content.